# flask & angular - Sending Python Output to URL

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am writing a small web app to test my understanding of integrating Angular 1 and Flask. When I try to send output from my Python function to the URL Localhost/synthesize_data, I see a Flask error: 'NoneType Object is not Subscriptable." It is trying to run my Python script again, but I only want it to show the output that the function should already have generated.

HTML with Angular:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
             'ngRoute',
            ]);

            myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
                 function($routeProvider) {
                     $routeProvider.
                         when('/', {
                             templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html',
                         }).
                         otherwise({
                             redirectTo: '/'
                         });
                }]);

            myApp.controller('formController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                console.log('HA');
                $scope.formData = {};
            $scope.processForm=function() {
                console.log("righthere")
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url : '/synthesize_data',
                    data : $scope.formData,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                })
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                })
            };
        }])

        </script>

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />-->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formController">
                <h1>Data Synthesizer Startup Page</h1>
        <div>
            <form ng-submit = "processForm()">
                <div id = "name-group" class = "form-group">
                    <label>Number of Rows to Create </label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "name" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter valid number input" ng-model = "formData.name">
                    <span class = "help-block"></span>
                </div>

                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                    <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit
                </button>
            </form>
    <!--<div ng-view></div>-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Python code (initialize program with hello()):

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, request
from data_synthesis import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/synthesize_data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def datasynthesize():
    print ("Calling synthesizer for ", request.json['name'], " rows.")
    main(int(request.json['name']))
    return "TEST"

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print ("Python up and running.")
    return send_file("templates/start.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

What I want is to see "TEST" on the screen when I run this program and navigate to Localhost/synthesize_data. Instead, it attempts to run my Python program again without proper input, which throws the error.

Comment: Please edit your code , it doesn't have correct indentation.

Comment: fixed, thanks for catching that.

Comment: How do you run your code ? and what error will be thrown ?

Comment: I run from the CLI with the command python hello.py. This starts the Flask server on Localhost. I input a number into the form and then the datasynthesize() function runs with my number as input. Everything works great here.
If I navigate to localhost/synthesize_data, I see an error: Type Error: NoneType object is not subscriptable. It seems to me that this means it is trying to run my Python script instead of just displaying "TEST" which is what I would like it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **only** execute the program when it has submitted form data you need to add a conditional into the view function. The code the way you have it is dependent on having the `name` value as part of the request.

[**Request.json**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.json) is `None` if the mimetype is not *application/json*. This is what is throwing the *'NoneType' Object is not Subscriptable* error when you're issue a `GET` request (e.g. when you navigate to *localhost/synthesize_data*). A better way of accomplishing this, per the Docs, is to use [**Request.get_json()**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json):

```
@app.route("/synthesize_data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def datasynthesize():
    data = request.get_json()
    if data:
        print ("Calling synthesizer for ", data['name'], " rows.")
        main(int(data['name']))
    return "TEST"
```